# Getting coordinates from geometry in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, geometry, coordinates, well-known-text, decimal-points

This line:

```sql
SELECT geom
FROM myLayer.geom
```

will return a hex value.

How would I get decimal values, which is a human-readable coordination?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

In addition to `ST_AsText` (which returns geometry as WKT / Well Known Text), there are several additional output formats, like `ST_AsGeoJSON()`.

Take a look in http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.0/reference.html#Geometry_Outputs and choose, what fits your needs best.

Answer (score 101):

Use [ST_AsText](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.0/ST_AsText.html) to view the point object:

```
SELECT ST_AsText(the_geom) 
       FROM myTable;
```

To view [X](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.0/ST_X.html), [Y](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.0/ST_Y.html), and the geom object:

```
SELECT ST_X(the_geom), ST_Y(the_geom), ST_AsText(the_geom) 
       FROM myTable;
```

Comment: I believe that ST_X & ST_Y will work only with points. They do not work with polygons or lines.

Comment: you are right Devdatta. it works only for points. _ST_X — Return the X coordinate of the point, or NULL if not available. Input must be a point._ i have updated my answer.

Comment: For polygons/lines, use `st_x(st_centroid(the_geom))`

Comment: @Aragon is the "the_geom" in your answer represents an object??does that mean that i can pass an object geometry?

Answer (score 22):

With a table in UTM

```
SELECT 
ST_X(table.geometry) AS X1, --point x
ST_Y(table.geometry) AS Y1, --point y
ST_X(ST_TRANSFORM(table.geometry,4674)) AS LONG, -- longitude point x SIRGAS 2000
ST_Y(ST_TRANSFORM(table.geometry,4674)) AS LAT, --latitude point y SIRGAS 2000
ST_ASTEXT(table.geometry) AS XY, --wkt point xy
ST_ASTEXT(ST_TRANSFORM(table.geometry,4674)) AS LongLat --using st_transform to get wkt with longitude and latitude (4674 is the SIRGAS 2000 SRC by south america)
FROM
table
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * ST_AsText(the_geom) FROM table2;
```

Source:
[Getting geometry from multiple tables using PostGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/8021/beginner-postgis-question-getting-geometry-from-multiple-tables)

Comment: You may need to add a , after the * , in order to properly separate fields:
SELECT *, ST_AsText(the_geom) FROM table2;