# How to convert shapefile to a set of Latitude and Longitude coordinates in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, field-calculator, layers, latitude-longitude

I am doing research in water and climate. I have downloaded a map for [World Water Bodies](https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=e750071279bf450cbd510454a80f2e63) that describes all the large water bodies that are drawn as polygons, and another map for small water bodies ([World Linear Water](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=273980c20bc74f94ac96c7892ec15aff))that are drawn as lines.

I am not a GIS expert, and I have only QGIS software, so I followed [this post to load the LPK file to QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/12974/free-tool-to-convert-arcgis-layer-package-lpk-to-shapefile-shp) then I tried [this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/74498/convert-shape-length-area-data-to-latitude-longitude) and [this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/23376/how-to-export-polygons-to-csv-with-coordinates) to convert this layer to a point-set of Longitude and Latitude coordinates. Unfortunately, I stuck in adding the calculated fields $x and $y to the layer, as it lasts for hours without real progress but "Not responding" while the `qgis-bin.exe` process in the Windows Task Manger shows about 2-10GB memory and 14% CPU of a core-i7/16G-RAM PC.

Layer 1 is 528MB size, and the Nodes file is 3GB with 38 Milion features!

Is there a method to speed up the conversion?

Am I doing the correct steps?

I just want a Long/Lat list (CSV) of the points surrounding the polygons of continents, seas, lakes, and big rivers, to use them in my research.

Comment: With such large datasets, you could consider importing your point shapefile to **PostGIS** and then calculate the coordinates as described in this post: [How to get coordinates from geometry in PostGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/42970/how-to-get-coordinates-from-geometry-in-postgis)

Comment: Thank you @Joseph for this advice, but I do not know what is PostGIS, is it an addon to qGIS, a standalone tool, or a python library?

Comment: Sorry @Joseph, I read about PostGIS, I know now it is a database client for GIS objects, OK, I will give it a try. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't test it right now but, if you want to convert the point shapefile to a CSV with lon/lat values, you may avoid using the **Field Calculator** (which is very time and resources consuming for 38 Million of features).

Firstly, deselect the layer from the **Layers Panel** and make sure that the **Attribute Table** for the same layer is not opened (this trick helped me in the past when dealing with some million features).

Then, right-click on the point layer in the Layers Panel, go to `Save As...` and use these options (you may change other options as you want, but make sure to select `AS_XY` in the `GEOMETRY` option):

[image]

This operation will create a CSV file which stores the same fields of the input point layer plus two additional field that store the Longitude and Latitude values. Please note that the whole operation may take some time because you are dealing with a 3GB file, but it should works (and it would be surely most efficient than using the Field Calculator in a preliminary step).

Comment: Many thanks for your advice, I am trying it right now.

Comment: Unfortunately, the method did not succeed! It exported just a list of shape_length and shape_area, No Latitudes and Longitudes. Example: OBJECTID,Name1,Name2,Name3,TYPE,ISO_CC,Shape_Length,Shape_Area
1, , , ,Inland intermittent,AO,0.0640761031664804,0.00016431571197887
2, , , ,Inland intermittent,AO,0.0366321064690917,3.80503219183659e-005
3, , , ,Inland intermittent,NA,0.187777497019295,0.000617306825186438
4, , , ,Inland intermittent,NA,0.0247112153483882,1.64606738052617e-005
5, , , ,Inland intermittent,NA,0.0117616719707985,5.90625617466775e-006

Comment: Wait please, I might performed something wrong, I will  confirm and come back shortly

Comment: @MohammadElNesr This procedure must be applied on a point shapefile. Let me know if it works then.

Comment: Please, could you tell me how to make a point shapefile?

Comment: @MohammadElNesr Maybe there was a misunderstanding. I assumed you were able to start from a point shapefile because I read _I tried this post and this post to convert this layer to a point-set of Longitude and Latitude coordinates_ from your question. Following this [post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/74498/convert-shape-length-area-data-to-latitude-longitude) that you have attached, were you able to extract the nodes from the polygons?

Comment: Many thanks, I already did it as I said, but I thought it is not what you mean.

Comment: @MohammadElNesr so, do you have a point layer to start from? I mean, a layer which has only points as geometries?

Comment: I made the pointLayer as instructed, then I converted it as you showed, but the exported CSV showed only the information showed above, in addition to Area and Perimeter!, See below:

Comment: OBJECTID,Name1,Name2,Name3,TYPE,ISO_CC,Shape_Leng,Shape_Area,area,perimeter
1,,,,Inland intermittent,AO,0.064076103166480,0.000164315711979,0.000164315711984,0.064076103166480
2,,,,Inland intermittent,AO,0.036632106469092,0.000038050321918,0.000038050321933,0.036632106469092
3,,,,Inland intermittent,NA,0.187777497019295,0.000617306825186,0.000617306825148,0.187777497019295
4,,,,Inland intermittent,NA,0.024711215348388,0.000016460673805,0.000016460673805,0.024711215348388

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57830/discussion-between-mgri-and-mohammad-elnesr).

Comment: It seems that something went wrong!

Comment: Many thanks @mgri I applied what you told me, it took 1hr to finish, but it succeded finally. Great Answer. Here is a sample output:`X,Y,OBJECTID,Name1,Name2,Name3,TYPE,ISO_CC,Shape_Leng,Shape_Area,area,perimeter
14.8248941895153,-17.1603608130011,1,,,,Inland intermittent,AO,0.064076103166480,0.000164315711979,0.000164315711984,0.064076103166480`

Comment: @MohammadElNesr, awesome! I'm glad it worked also for you.